# Unable to install QGIS Plugins on Windows

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, windows-10

I've installed QGIS 3.16 Hannover on my laptop about three days ago (Windows 10 Home 1909) and am unable to install any plugins, nor get access to any of the core plugins save four.
[image]

When going to settings, I get the ever-annoying "The settings on this tab are only applicable for Python Plugins. No Python support detected, thus no settings available" message.

Unlike most questions about this subject I've seen on here, updating didn't work; it still shows the same error.

Comment: How did you install qgis?

Comment: Through the QGIS site.
https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

Comment: I guess the question was about OSGeo4W Network Installer or Standalone installation. I assume you tried to restart your machine to see if that solves the problem?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to restart, the problem persists.

Comment: And which installer did you use?

Comment: I have the same problem and have tried installing both the LTS version from the standalone installer and the latest version from the network installer. I also tried uninstalling my python installation and then installing QGIS again. Any update on this?